# SQL INTERSECT by one field and get another field

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do this SQL query:

```
 SELECT field FROM table
 INTERSECT
 SELECT field FROM table
```

Which return the intersection by the given field, but I want to get another field from the table as a result (intersected by the given field), how do I do that?

Comment: Which dbms???????????????????????????????

Comment: i think you're asking for a [join](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/join)?

Answer (score 0):

I would use an EXISTS subquery:

```
SELECT t1.OtherField
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Table2 t2
        WHERE t2.Field = t1.Field
    )
```

Alternately, you can use an IN subquery, which may work better in some RDBMSs or configurations:

```
SELECT t1.OtherField
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE t1.Field IN (
        SELECT t2.Field
        FROM Table2 t2
    )
```

Comment: How to ensure return only one SELECT occurrence that satisfies the IN subset?

Comment: @juliocesar_io I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN`.

```
SELECT c1
FROM a
WHERE c2 IN (
        SELECT x1
        FROM b
        );
```

**Example:**

Table: `a`

```
c1  c2
------
1   10
2   20
3   30
```

Table: `b`

```
x1
---
20
30
```

**Result:**

```
c1
--
2
3
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/KCN83493)

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do it:

Look into [joins](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/join)

```
select 
    t1.AnyField, t2.AnyField
from 
    t1
    inner join t2 on t1.intersection_field = t2.intersection_field
```

Per your comment about the same table being involved

```
select 
    t1.AnyField, t2.AnyField
from 
    table as t1
    inner join table as t2 on t1.intersection_field = t2.intersection_field
      and t1.another_field = t2.another_field
```

or

```
select 
    t1.AnyField, t2.AnyField
from 
    table as t1
    inner join table as t2 on t1.intersection_field = t2.intersection_field
where
    t1.filtered_field = 'text'
    and t2.yet_another_field >= 10
```

Comment: How to make this on the same table with an additional condition?

Comment: @juliocesar_io see my edit. its very simple to join to the same table if you use [aliasing](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/alias)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT anotherField 
FROM table b
JOIN table1 a ON a.field=b.field
```